# Why does my app never call BluetoothGattCallback.OnServicesDiscovered?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, android-bluetooth

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms (version 4.8.0.1687) cross-platform app that will need to be able to connect to other instances of itself using Bluetooth LE. I am using the shared interfaces/platform-specific implementations pattern for BLE. I have hit a snag when trying to read the service from Android when it's acting as the central: I am unable ever to discover the services on the device acting as the peripheral, meaning that the **OnServicesDiscovered** callback method is never called (at least, not within 20 minutes). To try to isolate the problem I have stripped the connection/service discovery code down to an extremely short version, but I'm still having the problem. These are in my **BluetoothGattCallback**-derived implementation:

```
public override void OnConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, [GeneratedEnum] GattStatus status, [GeneratedEnum] ProfileState newState)
{
    base.OnConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);

    if (ProfileState.Connected == newState)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1001); // Several articles I've read recommend a delay of at least 600 ms before calling DiscoverServices
        gatt.DiscoverServices(); // a breakpoint set here is reliably triggered
    }
    else
    {
        gatt.Close();
    }
}

public override void OnServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, [GeneratedEnum] GattStatus status)
{
    base.OnServicesDiscovered(gatt, status); // a breakpoint set here is never triggered

    if (GattStatus.Success == status)
    {
        this.hasDiscoveredServices = true;
    }
}
```

I am sure the service is set up and included, because I can see it and read its characteristics on the same device from an iOS instance of the app. It's hard to imagine what I could be missing in something this simple, but I'm hoping someone with more knowledge and experience will see what it is.

EDIT: I found an article that said the Android BLE API will always use BR/EDR if a peripheral indicates it has the capability, and I wondered if that could be my problem. I used **Java.Lang.Reflect** to dig out a reference to a hidden version of **connectGatt** that allows you to set the transport protocol explicitly and...no joy. Exactly the same - **OnConnectionStateChange** is called, with apparent success, but **OnServicesDiscovered** is never called at all.

EDIT: I discovered by accident that if I connect, disconnect, and connect again during the same peripheral advertising session or burst or whatever the right word is, that then calling **DiscoverServices** does result in **OnServicesDiscovered** being called within a second, but **BluetoothGatt.Services** has no elements. I'm not sure if this is progress or not.

EDIT: If I just keep running the same connect-disconnect-reconnect-discover-services over and over, once in a while - maybe once in 10 tries, or once in 15? - it does discover services and the **Services** property is populated. That's obviously not good enough for actual use. Is it possible that I'm just testing with crummy hardware? Is Android simply rubbish under the hood?

EDIT: On a brand-new Galaxy Tab S7 the behavior seems to be exactly the same. Experimenting further, but at this point I'm seriously tempted to recommend shelving the Android project.

Comment: You could check the HCI log in the phone to see if the Bluetooth stack is buggy, or there is some outer issue. It would also be good if you tried to use nRF Connect or another BLE debug app to see if it works correctly from there. And also to try another Android phone as central.

Comment: Hm. Despite being in developer mode, the Settings does not offer a Developer Options choice, which everything I'm seeing says is the way to enable HCI logging. Maybe this is just a crap device. I have a new Galaxy coming from the office soon; maybe that will clear things up.